# Python parse js to list

Tags: python, list, parsing, python-requests

we have a problem to parse js to list. This similiar with json parse, but in my problem only need to put data from list of `"markers"`.

Example, we have data from http://localhost:4000/static/libary/jogja.js

```
var jogjaAddress = {
    "cityname": "Jogja",
    "lat"     : "-7.8722732",
    "lon"     : "110.1440828",

    "markers": [
        {
            "name": "Keraton Yogyakarta",
            "lat": "-7.8052845",
            "lon": "110.3642031",
            "image":"http://wisatanesia.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/keraton-yogya.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Malioboro",
            "lat": "-7.793997",
            "lon": "110.3634648",
            "image": "http://anekatempatwisata.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Malioboro.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Masjid Gedhe Kauman",
            "lat": "-7.803951",
            "lon": "110.3599771",
            "image": "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E0lKq6W1M_g/TloYV5CmAJI/AAAAAAAADao/JefvauzcAv8/s1600/L1290134.JPG"
        },
        {
            "name": "Taman Sari",
            "lat": "-7.8099632",
            "lon": "110.3567511",
            "image": "http://www.maestrobali.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Taman-Sari-Water-Castle1.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, output should be:

```
myList = [
    {
        "name": "Keraton Yogyakarta",
        "lat": "-7.8052845",
        "lon": "110.3642031",
        "image":"http://wisatanesia.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/keraton-yogya.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Malioboro",
        "lat": "-7.793997",
        "lon": "110.3634648",
        "image": "http://anekatempatwisata.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Malioboro.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Masjid Gedhe Kauman",
        "lat": "-7.803951",
        "lon": "110.3599771",
        "image": "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E0lKq6W1M_g/TloYV5CmAJI/AAAAAAAADao/JefvauzcAv8/s1600/L1290134.JPG"
    },
    {
        "name": "Taman Sari",
        "lat": "-7.8099632",
        "lon": "110.3567511",
        "image": "http://www.maestrobali.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Taman-Sari-Water-Castle1.jpg"
    }
]
```

#### Edit:

```
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get('http://localhost:4000/static/libary/jogja.js')
>>> resp.text #or resp.content, it will return string
```

Can I take the data from `"markers"` to list?

Thanks so much before.

Comment: I cannot figure out what the problem is. What is the question?

Comment: Please post what you've tried and what error you've gotten.

Comment: It's very confusing. Is this js or json? It's nice to give a link from where data are retrieved but nobody will find from your localhost...

Comment: like... `myList = json.load(JSON_FILE)['markers']`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen -- _almost_.  json would choke on the `var jogjaAddress =` bit.

Comment: @mgilson hense `JSON_FILE` and not `JS_SCRIPT`, being a variable imbedded in a javascript file means that some level of parsing would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is *almost* json.  It should be good enough to split on the first `=` and then parse with the standard library json module:

```
json_data = data.split('=', 1)[1]
myList = json.loads(json_data)['markers']
```

Here's a demo from my terminal:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = """var jogjaAddress = {
...     "cityname": "Jogja",
...     "lat"     : "-7.8722732",
...     "lon"     : "110.1440828",
... 
...     "markers": [
...         {
...             "name": "Keraton Yogyakarta",
...             "lat": "-7.8052845",
...             "lon": "110.3642031",
...             "image":"http://wisatanesia.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/keraton-yogya.jpg"
...         },
...         {
...             "name": "Malioboro",
...             "lat": "-7.793997",
...             "lon": "110.3634648",
...             "image": "http://anekatempatwisata.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Malioboro.jpg"
...         },
...         {
...             "name": "Masjid Gedhe Kauman",
...             "lat": "-7.803951",
...             "lon": "110.3599771",
...             "image": "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E0lKq6W1M_g/TloYV5CmAJI/AAAAAAAADao/JefvauzcAv8/s1600/L1290134.JPG"
...         },
...         {
...             "name": "Taman Sari",
...             "lat": "-7.8099632",
...             "lon": "110.3567511",
...             "image": "http://www.maestrobali.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Taman-Sari-Water-Castle1.jpg"
...         }
...     ]
... }"""
...
>>> json_data = s.split('=', 1)[1]
>>> myList = json.loads(json_data)['markers']
>>> myList
[{u'lat': u'-7.8052845', u'image': u'http://wisatanesia.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/keraton-yogya.jpg', u'lon': u'110.3642031', u'name': u'Keraton Yogyakarta'}, {u'lat': u'-7.793997', u'image': u'http://anekatempatwisata.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Malioboro.jpg', u'lon': u'110.3634648', u'name': u'Malioboro'}, {u'lat': u'-7.803951', u'image': u'http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E0lKq6W1M_g/TloYV5CmAJI/AAAAAAAADao/JefvauzcAv8/s1600/L1290134.JPG', u'lon': u'110.3599771', u'name': u'Masjid Gedhe Kauman'}, {u'lat': u'-7.8099632', u'image': u'http://www.maestrobali.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Taman-Sari-Water-Castle1.jpg', u'lon': u'110.3567511', u'name': u'Taman Sari'}]
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. yap, therefore I said similar with json data. I'm sorry for my question that difficult to understand..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm going to assume this is JSON that you're parsing.  If you put more information in the comments, I might be able to help more

```
import json

resp = {your JSON String}

json_dict = json.loads(resp)

print(json_dict[markers])
```

This seems like a pretty straightforward use of the JSON module that comes with Python, have you done any research on this?  Look [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked too many times, your variable jogjaAddress is a dictionary, so you should treat it like so. Consider reading  pythons documentation on Data structures: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary). A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing
>   a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds
>   initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way
>   dictionaries are written on output.

and retrieve the element by "key" which according to your code is "markers"

in other words:

`jogjaAddress ["markers"]` is equal to the output you are looking for.